# Is it insecure to make Perl's prove command NOPASSWD in sudoers file?

Tags: security, sudo, perl

I've got a Perl test script, initiated with `prove`, that tests a backup script that requires root privileges so rsync can change the permissions on the files it downloaded from a remote server.

So I've got the following in my Mac's sudoers file:

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/path/to/prove
```

It works. But my question is, since `prove` can be used to run pretty much any perl script written by the local user, is this a huge security risk?

Comment: It' yes, because anyone can write a Perl script to run any command as root. Just don't do it.

Comment: this is no different to allowing perl or awk or bash or any other script interpreter to be run as root....and, as they can run other programs, it's equivalent to allowing ANY program to be run as root with any args.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that approach is insecure.

Write a specific wrapper that specifically runs your command which subsequently calls the `prove`, secure it so that only root can modify it, and put it somewhere only root can reach.  Then, add *that* wrapper to the `sudoers` file.

Don't allow parameters in your script.

NB: Although, even that's open to abuse, if someone can modify either the first perl script, or the backup script.  Have to ensure everything in the chain is modifiable only by `root`.